# Como verificar se dados já existem ou ficaram em branco?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Eu estava testando os cadastros do site que fiz, e notei que consegui cadastrar o mesmo username 2 vezes, mesmo tendo declarado "UNIQUE" na tabela.

E outra coisa, notei também que embora eu tenha deixado os campos obrigatórios, caso alguém digite espaço, o registro é feito com sucesso. Como impedir que algo do tipo aconteça?

Abaixo é o código de inserção no banco de dados:

```
<?php

// captura dos dados digitados no formulário //
$nome=$_POST ['nome'];
$sobrenome=$_POST ['sobrenome'];
$username=$_POST ['username'];
$email=$_POST ['email'];
$senha=$_POST ['senha'];
$telefone=$_POST ['telefone'];

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO cadastro (nome,sobrenome,username,email,senha,telefone)  VALUES ('$nome', '$sobrenome','$username','$email','$senha','$telefone')") or die(mysql_error());

$resultado = mysql_query ($sql);
header ("Location:../usuario/index.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

essa mesma inserçao com pdo ficaria assim com a remoçao de espaços

```
$host = "localhost";
$user = "seu usuario";
$pass = "sua senha";
$banco = "seu banco de dados";

$conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$banco.'',$user,$pass);

if(empty($_POST['username'])){
    echo "Username vazio!";
}else{
   $nome = $_POST['nome'];
   $sobrenome = $_POST['sobrenome'];
   $username = trim($_POST['username']);
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $senha = $_POST['senha'];
   $telefone = $_POST['telefone'];

   $insere = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO cadastro (nome,sobrenome,username,email,senha,telefone)  VALUES ('$nome', '$sobrenome','$username','$email','$senha','$telefone')");
   $insere->execute();


   if($insere){
      echo "Inserido com sucesso!";
   }else{
      echo "Erro ao inserir!";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Remoção dos espaços

Caso você esteja validando no Javascript com Jquery, é possível fazer o seguinte:

```
var nome = $('#nome').val().trim(); // O método trim remove os espaços

if(nome === ''){
    alert('Preencha o nome!');
}
```

Para remover os espaços no PHP, existe a função [`trim`](http://php.net/trim):

```
// Com trim os espaços são removidos das strings
$nome      = trim($_POST['nome']);
$sobrenome = trim($_POST['sobrenome']);
$username  = trim($_POST['username']);
$email     = trim($_POST['email']);
// Aqui seriam colocados o restante dos campos...
```

#### Impedindo inserções duplicadas no banco

Para evitar a duplicação, você precisa verificar se o registro existe antes de inseri-lo. Ou seja, é preciso fazer uma query para checar se o username já foi inserido antes. O campo username é o que estou utilizando como exemplo, caso seja outro campo que vai definir se o usuário é único, basta utilizá-lo no lugar de username.

A query ficaria assim:

```
SELECT id FROM tabela WHERE username = '$username' LIMIT 1
```

Caso a query retorne resultados, significa que o usuário já existe, sabendo disso basta verificar o resultado antes de fazer o insert. Lembrando que `tabela` deve ser substituído pelo nome da tabela que você está usando no seu banco de dados.

PS: Recomendo você utilizar a PDO, pois as funções `mysql_*` estão em desuso. Também recomendo a filtragem dos dados enviados por POST, para isso é existe a função [`filter_input`](http://php.net/filter_input)do PHP.

Comment: Poxa Raphael, muito obrigada pela ajuda, vou testar ainda sobre a verificação. Sobre a remoção de espaços, eu estou validando todos os dados direto pelo php, e por lá eu tentei alguns códigos e não funcionou como eu queria.